# Changed characters in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, appearance

In the screenshot you can see side by side comparison between Chromium and Chrome. The settings are identical and I've already tried Reset settings.

[image]

Comment: It looks you have a font slightly larger in one case.  Did you try `Ctrl +`(or `Ctr - `) to change font size?

Comment: Yes it's not that....